# Vue.js: EventBus.$on received value is not propagating

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am fairly new to vue and trying to figure out the best way to structure my event bus. I have a main layout view (`Main.vue`) inside of which I have a router view that I am passing a child's emitted info to like so:

```
<template>
<layout>
<router-view :updatedlist="mainupdate" />
</layout>
</template>
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      mainupdate: []
    }
  },
mounted () {
    EventBus.$on('listupdated', item => {
      this.mainupdate = item
      console.log(item)
    })
  }
}
```

The structure looks like: `Main.vue` contains `Hello.vue` which calls `axios` data that it feeds to child components `Barchart.vue`, `Piechart.vue`, and `Datatable.vue`

The axios call in `Hello.vue` populates a data property called `list`. I then check if `updatedlist` (passed as router prop from `Datatable.vue` to `Main.vue` when something changes) is empty, and if so set it to the value of `list`

I know that the event is being emitted and received by `Main.vue` because the `console.log(item)` shows the data. But my child components are not getting updated, even though they are using `updatedlist` as their data source. (If I reload the page, they will be updated btw, but why aren't they reactive?)

**UPDATE:** I thought I would cut out the top level parent `Main.vue` and just put my EventBus$on inside `Hello.vue` instead and then just change `list` when it was received. But this does two things, neither of which are great:

1. On every page refresh, my console logs add one more log to the list and output all of them. So for example if I have made 3 changes, there will be three logs, 4 there will be 4, etc. The list grows until I restart the app.
2. My child components are STILL not updated :(

**UPDATE 2:** UGH. I think I see why they aren't updating, the problem is with the reactivity in my chartsjs component, so I will have to resolve that there (`Barchart.vue`, `Piechart.vue`). A simple component I built myself to just read the total length DOES get updated, so that works. This still leaves the mystery of the massive number of duplicate console logs though, any ideas?

Comment: Can you show where you instantiate the event bus?

Comment: Sure, it is inside a `saveData` method inside the `Datatable.vue` file. It works fine I know, because as I said above `Main.vue` receives it (verified in console)

Comment: and sorry, if I misunderstood you I added my import statement above, which pulls from a file that has two lines in it: `import Vue from 'vue'` and 
`export const EventBus = new Vue()`

Comment: What do your child components look like? Specifically, what do they do with the `updatedlist` prop?

Comment: Well, as you can see by my update above, I have now tried to simplify (but no luck) by simply changing the original list property value when the event is received, but no luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may have the answer to the original question? To answer your last update you likely have duplicate logs because you do not appear to be removing event handlers. When you add an event handler to a bus like this:

```
mounted () {
    EventBus.$on('listupdated', item => {
      this.mainupdate = item
      console.log(item)
    })
  }
}
```

You *need* to remove it yourself. Otherwise you are just adding a new handler *every* time the component is mounted.

I suggest you move the actual handler into a method:

```
methods: {
  onListUpdated(item){
     this.mainupdate = item
     console.log(item)
  }
}
```

Move code to add the handler to created:

```
created() {
    EventBus.$on('listupdated', this.onListUpdate)
  }
}
```

And *add* a beforeDestroy handler:

```
beforeDestroy(){
   EventBus.$off("listupdated", this.onListUpdate)
}
```

And do that in every component that you are adding event handlers to `EventBus`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it will be very helpful in the future. I actually solved the repeating logs problem by pushing my EventBus.$on listen to the lowest level needed (the charts in this case) and updated there. But I suspect you are right that when I had the listener attached at the parent or grandparent level, I was confronted with this problem and yours is probably the solution.

Comment: Actually, a quick question: Since this is NOT happening in my lowest level component, yet you recommend doing this in every component, any idea why?

Comment: @Stephen It matters when you add the handler. If you add it in `created`, then the component might not actually be created/destroyed multiple times (even if it is unmounted). If it ever gets created twice though, you will add a duplicate handler. If you add it in mounted it will be added every time the component is mounted.

Comment: Thanks @Bert. Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day. Glod blesses you.

Answer (score 0):

I' not aware if you require to stick to the current structure. For me the following works perfectly fine.

```
// whereever you bootstrap your vue.js
// e.g.
window.Vue = require('vue');

// add a central event bus
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();
```

Now you can simply access the event bus in every component by using

```
this.$bus.$on( ... )
```

As said I'm not aware of your full event bus code but this should actually work fine

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a whirl and report back, it can't hurt.

Comment: Alas no. I get exactly the same weird console logging (too many times) and lack of child updates.

Comment: You will need to post more of your code and setup then. It's hard to tell from what we see